# Selecting sets that maximise the cardinality of the union minus the cardinality of the difference

Tags: algorithms, optimization, discrete-mathematics, sets, integer-programming

I have a sparse $60000\times10000$ matrix where each element is either a $1$ or $0$ as follows.

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Each row represents a different point in time such that the first row is $t=1$ and the last row is $t=60000$. Each column in the matrix is a different combination of signals (ie. $1$s and $0$s).
I want to choose five column vectors from $M$, $c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4, c_5$ and take the Hadamard (ie. element-wise) product:

$$s = c_1 \circ c_2 \circ c_3 \circ c_4 \circ c_5$$

The result is a new vector $s$ where $1$s only remain in a row if they were present in every vector $c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4, c_5$ for that row. I need an algorithm that finds the optimal strategy vector $s_{opt}$ that is most similar to the optimal strategy vector $s^{*}$. The optimal strategy vector $s^{*}$ is predefined and static, of the same dimensions as $s$, and has the optimal placement of 1s and 0s.

In terms of the approach, I think a viable solution is to turn every column $j$ into a set and save the row numbers where there is a 1 in that column, $\lbrace i:M_{ij}=1\rbrace$. For example, column one in $M$ would become $\lbrace 1,2,...\rbrace$, column two would be $\lbrace 2,3,...\rbrace$, column three would be $\lbrace 1,...\rbrace$ and so forth. This then becomes the 'Maximum k-Subset Intersection Problem' where $k=5$ as I want to select five sets that define the strategy s_{opt} that maximise the cardinality of their intersection with the target set $s^{*}$.

In other words $max|s_{opt} \cap s^{*}|$ where $s_{opt} = c_1 \cap c_2 \cap c_3 \cap c_4 \cap c_5$

However a cost must be incorporated into the optimisation function. This cost should be the number of false positives (ie. a $1$ in a row of the column vector $s_{opt}$ but a $0$ in that very row for $s^*$). Using the sets, this could be computed as $|s_{opt} \setminus s^{*}|$.

Thus the optimisation function becomes: $max|s_{opt} \cap s^{*}| - |s_{opt} \setminus s^{*}|$ which can be thought of as the number of true positives minus the number of false positives.

I found an [academic paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/344137357_Reactive_VNS_algorithm_for_the_maximum_k-subset_intersection_problem) implementing an algorithm to solve a similar problem but to be honest I don't understand how to implement it nor tweak it to my problem. **Any help is much appreciated! :)**